# Remove string until the second occurrence in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

My shell script does the following:

```
grep '<record' /data/error/usage_20160422_165920.lerr.xml|sed -e 's/&apos;//g'|cut -d ';' -f1,40,43,46
```

The result will looks like

```
<record record_no = "1" error_code="101">;RevShare-2.txt;TWN;1
```

I want to remove xml tags `<record record_no = "1" error_code=` and result should look like `101;RevShare-2.txt;TWN;1`;

Record nos# are dynamic.

EDIT: I have added `cut -d '=' -f3|tr -d '",>'` to achieve this. This works but it is taking 3 seconds to process a file containing 20,000 records. I have 500 files coming daily. Is there a better way to speed up this process?

EDIT : Here is how the record look like.

```
<record record_no = "1" error_code="101">&apos;&apos;;&apos;25467&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;FIRSTNAME&apos;;&apos;Manikin&apos;;&apos;1234001&apos;;&apos;12484254823&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;103&apos;;&apos;12484254815&apos;;&apos;XXXXX9680&apos;;&apos;OFX&apos;;&apos;0&apos;;&apos;1028000002130745&apos;;&apos;20160422&apos;;&apos;0000&apos;;&apos;25467&apos;;&apos;20160422&apos;;&apos;Y&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;6&apos;;&apos;2&apos;;&apos;1&apos;;&apos;0&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;263&apos;;&apos;99&apos;;&apos;N&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;Idverifyprod@50&apos;;&apos;136&apos;;&apos;7, 74, 77, 80, 105, 136, 153&apos;;&apos;0&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;501&apos;;&apos;RevShare-2.txt&apos;;&apos;20160422165920&apos;;&apos;000009680&apos;;&apos;TWN&apos;;&apos;1449587762538&apos;;&apos;1&apos;;&apos;1&apos;;&apos;0&apos;;&apos;&apos;;&apos;Verifier&apos;
</record>
```

Comment: can you add complete xml 'record' line. so we can think on a solution?

Comment: `grep | sed | cut` is almost always better spelled  `awk`.  That is certainly true in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
/<record/ {
    gsub(/&apos;/,"")
    gsub(/.*="|">/,"",$1)
    print $1, $40, $43, $46
}
' /data/error/usage_20160422_165920.lerr.xml
101;RevShare-2.txt;TWN;1
```

Comment: Awesome! I didnt know how to use gsub so efficiently. I probably can write this in awk function and use it. As requested, i have added the actual input i was trying to test.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh okay. I don't know much of the subject so thought of leaving that comment when I came across this post in the LQPHQ.

Comment: @EdMorton I want to append the input file to the awk out, how to do that, for e.g I have done this `sed "s/$/;$new_err_xml/g"` append the file at the end.

Comment: i got it please review: `BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
/<record/ {
    gsub(/&apos;/,"")
    gsub(/.*="|">/,"",$1)
    print $1, $40, $43, $46, FILENAME

}' TWN_new_usage_20160422_165920.fin.bc_lerr.xml
`

Comment: @EdMorton I ran in to an issue. The data came in as `<record record_no = "2" error_code="101">&apos;22006153&` , the awk is printing the data as 10122006153. How to solve ?

Answer (score 0):

When the other fields don't have strings like `error_code`, you can do something like

```
 | sed 's/.* error_code="[^"]*">/\1/'
```

Can you combine the different commands? Something like

```
cut -d ';' -f1,40,43,46 /data/error/usage_20160422_165920.lerr.xml|
   sed -n '/<record/p;s/&apos;//g;s/.* error_code="[^"]*">/\1/'
```

Comment: When you have applied 3 bandaids to a wound and it's still bleeding, there's a better solution than adding a 4th bandaid or reducing it to 2 bandaids - just replace them all with one bigger bandaid (awk).

Comment: @Ed Yes, awk is better. I didn;t had the right first-aid kit in my car.